# setting value from sql query to object

Tags: sql

```
select pb.id,
    p.name,
    pb.batchName,
    pb.batchCode,
    s.detail,pb.program_id,
    pb.session_id,
    si.typeDescp,
    si.id 
from programBatch_info pb 
join program p on pb.program_id=p.id
join session_info s on pb.session_id=s.id
join semester_info si on si.id=pb.semInfo_id
```

Here the name of first and last columns is 'id' so when I retrieve the values of this query first column object and last column object return the same value.But when I change the 'si.id' to 'pb.semInfo_id' the name of last column is'semInfo_id' and hence the correct values is retrieved. I tried this native query in hibernate platform.
Am I conceputally wrong or what is the actual case??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the question but try this:

```
select pb.id,
    p.name,
    pb.batchName,
    pb.batchCode,
    s.detail,pb.program_id,
    pb.session_id,
    si.typeDescp,
    si.id as [si_id]
from programBatch_info pb 
join program p on pb.program_id=p.id
join session_info s on pb.session_id=s.id
join semester_info si on si.id=pb.semInfo_id
```

This is the syntax to specify a new column name.